# Java generics question

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, oop

So I have 3 classes.

```
Abstract class A 

Class B extends class A

independent Class C
```

In class D that contains the main method, I create a list of instances of class B

```
List<B> b =  methodCall(); // the method returns a list of instances of class B
```

Now in class C I have one method that is common to both A and B, and hence I don't want to duplicate it. I want to have one method that takes as input an instance of class A, as follows:

```
public void someMethod(List<A> a)
```

However, when I do:

```
C c = new C();
c.someMethod(b);
```

I get an error that some-method is not applicable for the argument `List<B>`, instead it's expecting to get `List<A>`.

Is there a good way to fix this problem?
Many thanks!

Comment: This isn't an inheritance question, it's a generics question.  Review the generics tutorial.  It's a good reference for this kind of question: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf

Comment: Can you include the actual function definitions and a copy of the error you are getting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a method which expects `List<A>`, and a class `B extends A`, and you want to pass this method a `List<B>`, then you should declare the method as:

```
public void someMethod(List<? extends A> list)
```

This allows the list passed to the method to be a List of A or anything that extends B.

Note though that you will not be able to tell the exact type of `?` passed into the method.

Also, if you have duplicated methods between two classes, that's probably a sign that something is off with your design.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void someMethod(List<? extends A> a){ //...
```

Comment: Well, the question keeps getting edited so now I don't know if the poster was trying to use generics or not.

Answer (score 1):

In your method signature you have `List<A> a` which means it only accepts a list of objects of type `A`. What you need is something that accepts a list of `A` and `any subtype of A` (or a family of subtypes of A).

What you need is this:

```
public void someMethod(List<? extends A> list) {
  ...
}
```